# Incorporating back changes made in clones of a read-only repository

Tags: git

Here is a hypothetical situation I can't get out of my head.

Within a School a Teacher creates a master git repo and branches for each of his students in a shared read only directory. (Assume that IT will not permit a Git server instance or ports for internet based solution)

Students can clone a single branch and commit locally but cannot push changes to the shared directory as it is read only.

Could the teacher repo some how collect/merge changes from the respective students?

Comment: Why would you disallow pushing? That seems like the nicest solution to me.

Comment: Students have a nasty habit of deleting stuff for fun, I guess if git push could somehow limit their power to their branch it could be viable. But it is still a read only drive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, and there's more than one way to do that:

- Git has the `git format-patch` command which is able to prepare a patch or a series of patches based on the work done against some already existing commit.

  So, the first obvious idea is to have the students generate the patch set from their changes and send it via e-mail to their teacher.  The teacher then uses `git am` to incorporate the changes (to the appropriate braches).
- If that's inconvenient for some reason (you have originally tagged your question `windows`; I have removed this tag) — say, the teacher and/or the students are inexperienced enough to properly use e-mail clients or only have access to broken e-mail clients like Microsoft® Outlook™, — you might use `git bundle`.

  `git bundle` is able to generate a single "archive" file in a special format containing the specified bits of history (it's easy to tell `git bundle` to export only the work done against the history initially supplied by the teacher) and then deliver this file using any convenient means: carry on a flash drive, send by e-mail, upload to a FTP or a shared folder etc.

  The teacher can then `git fetch` or `git pull` from the bundles supplied by the students to get the initial branches updated.

Note that unless you deploy some "front-end" software like `gitolite` it's impossible to make students only have access to their personal branch for cloning.

---

Note also that's there's nothing unusual about "serverless" Git workflows: say, the very Git development process relies on submitting patches (usually prepared by `git format-patch` or `git send-email`) to the main Git mailing list, discussing them there — by directly commenting on the messages containing patches, — and applying patches saved from developers' mail readers.  [See for yourself](http://news.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git), and [this](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/SubmittingPatches).

Moreover, "the server" is not really needed even when not using e-mail: if developers Joe and Mary have, say, SSH access to each other's boxes, they might just access each other's repos directly.  A central repo on a central server is just a useful concept but is mostly a social thing, not technical.

Answer (score 1):

If the students' repos are reachable by the teacher on the network, yes. The teacher would need to setup a remote for each student, then fetch and merge (pull) their branches.

Ideally, students would have their local repos, commit locally, then publish (push) their work in a bare repository on the network. They could then notify the teacher (pull request) that their work is done in their public repo in a name-given branch. The teacher can fetch the branch, and if the work is worthy, merge it.

This is how github works, someone owns a project (the teacher), people can fork it (make a clone on their machine, and on their github account), work on a branch, then when they want the owner to take their changes they push their changes from their machine to their fork on github, and the owner can look at the branch (for example by fetching) and possibly merge it to their own repo.

If the teacher cannot access the students' local repo directly, the students have to push somewhere, and in a DVCS they typically do that in their own (bare) clone on a network.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification about bare repos, but the situation is probably best served by a patch file a concept none specialists would readily understand as a zip.

Answer (score 0):

you could commit the changes locally to your branch. then do a pull request from their master branch. If you have access to push directly to their branch you would 
use the git push http://github.com/teachersUsername/repoName.git 
then provide your credentials(username and password)